# .hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, node-modules

I'm trying to refer a foreign key between 2 models.
but I'm getting this error:

`throw new Error(this.name + '.hasMany called with something that\'s not a subclass of Sequelize.Model');`
      ^

Error: user_relation.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

**squelize.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('./default.config')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.user, config.password, {
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  timezone: config.timezone,//东八区
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(err => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**User model**

const sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const Model = require('../../config/squelize');

```
const Admin = Model.define('admin', {
  username : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : false},//用户名
  password : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : false},//密码
  details : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : true},//简介
  head_thumb : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : true},//头像
  gender : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : true},//性别
  nickname : {type : sequelize.STRING, allowNull : true},//昵称
  userid : {type : sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement : true, primaryKey : true}//用户userid
}, {
  freezeTableName:true
})

module.exports = Admin;
```

**admin_relation.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Model = require('../../config/squelize');
const Admin = require('./admin.model')

var user_relation = Model.define('user_relation', {
    id : {type : Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement : true, primaryKey : true},
    userid : {type : Sequelize.STRING, allowNull : false},//用户id
    frendid : {type : Sequelize.STRING, allowNull : false}//朋友id
},{
    timestamps:false,
    freezeTableName:true,
});
user_relation.hasMany(Admin,{as:'admin',foreignKey:'userid'})

module.exports = user_relation;
```

Does someone have already see an error that look like that ? I search for few days without any issue, if someone could help I'll really appreciate,

thank !

Answer (score 4):

If this is many to many scenario, it's better to create a new model and in that model, you can add the relationship. Otherwise, put the relation in One side.

```
Admin.belongsTo(User);
```

and also in admin side you can put

```
User.hasMany(Admin);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to maintain a foreign key in user_relation model for the userid key in Admin model. If that is so, you have to define sourceKey and targetKey in association.

Define both sourceKey and targetKey with same datatype.

**In Admin model**

```
Admin.belongsTo(user_relation, {
    foreignKey: 'userid',
    targetKey: 'userid'
});
```

**In user_relation model**

```
user_relation.hasMany(Admin, {
    as: 'admin',
    foreignKey: 'userid',
    sourceKey: 'userid'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was caused by me saving different models in different .js files.
I was then requiring all of them in a single initialize.js file and then defining the associations, such as hasMany and belongsTo.
This was apparently causing a problem.

I moved all my Models to a single file and described the associations in the same file and it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: This worked for me, apparently it has something to do with the order the files are loaded in

Comment: This is at best a workaround, not really a solution. Keeping models in different files is standard practice in MCV as it helps to keep complex codebases managable.

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue still - the issue for me was the order the files were loaded in vs where had the association declared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.